# How to deploy outlook addin using Graph API

Tags: deployment, microsoft-graph-api, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a javascript outlook addin implemented and want to deploy the addin to all the users in the organisation. I want to use the Graph API however did not find anything in the Graph API reference. Is there a graph call available? even if it is in beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) doesn't provide anything for that.

All the possible deployment methods/ways are described in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.